# Ternary operator inside useState. Is it correct?

Tags: reactjs

I am setting a component that receive a specific prop. This prop is the resulting object of a `find` method on the parent component. The state would be the controller of an input on a form.

When the `find` method does not find anything, it returns an undefined. I defined my state this way:

```
const [foo, setFoo] = useState(props.bar? props.bar._id : "");
```

This works great, but I'm wondering if it's correct to do it like that.

Comment: not good idea, you can do it like: `const [foo, setFoo] = useState(props.bar || "");`

Comment: But im trying to store a property of the bar object, and if I do `const [foo, setFoo] = useState(props.bar._id || "");` I will be getting the error of can't read property _id of undefined.

Comment: I think you could also use `useState(props.bar && props.bar._id)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly correct and valid.

I personally, like to create a `const initialState` to make it a little easier to read.

```js
const Example = (props) => {
  const initialState = props.bar ? props.bar._id : '';
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState(initialState);

  return { foo };
};
```

As far as accessing `_id` when `bar` is undefined. There are a few ways to solve that as well.

One of the new ways to do so is to use the new optional chaining operator `?.` and the nullish coalescing operator `??` together.

```js
const initialState = props.bar?._id ?? '';
```

If you don't have support for those new operators you could also use the `||` or operator like so.

```js
const initialState = (props.bar || {})._id || '';
```

Comment: yeah even i agree that its valid but to increase redability you can just separate the operator into a constant

Comment: @GayatriDipali I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: i just meant that instead of having your turnary operator directly inside your useState() ,create a variable and assign the turnary operator to it and then pass it insisde useState().  **i just wrote what @Benjamin showed in code**